# Best Metadata Standard for creating a directory

Tags: xml, directory, metadata, standards, dublin-core

Does anyone have a favorite metadata standard (ex. Dublin Core) for creating a directory in conjuction with the DDI? This directory would include Age,Mailing Address, and Work Addresses, as well is a LicenseID Information (which would be unique to the individual).

Comment: What are your criteria for making the choice? Just being someone's "favorite"?

Comment: One that allow to make a person to create directories involving listing a person's age, licenseID, Race, Personal Mailing Address, Work Addresses (both Primary & Secondary--if applicable).